# Caching maps within an android app

Tags: android

I am looking to create an app where users can download a map to their phone before they go to a specific place (in case there is no 3G signal there) and then use GPS to take specific routes that will have been marked on the maps.

I have noticed GoogleMaps 5 has just been released that enables caching. 
Is this something I would be able to use or can you not incorporate google maps 5 into another app.

I am very new to Android and am not quite sure what can and can't be done as yet so 'm sorry if 
this is a really silly question?

Thanks for any help!

Bex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this something I would be able to use or can you not incorporate google maps 5 into another app.

Google Maps (the app) does not use the same Google Maps (the SDK add-on) that the rest of us use. Hence, right now, offline caching is not available to us.

You might consider looking at OpenStreetMap, which has some Android integration and supports offline maps.

Comment: Bah! Not fair. Will have a look at openstreetmap tho!